# OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android - gl_FragCoord and gl_FragColor

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-fragments

After a few day with a lot of researching and tests I finally was able to implement the Fragment Shader that is shown is this book (an excellent book, may I say): http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tutorial%2002.html.

It just teaches how to render a simple triangle with a Fragment Shader that uses "gl_FragCoord.y".

In these working days however I went throught some issues that I would like to understand a little better why them happened.

**1st** - In my fragment shader, if I use the code:
`gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x/500.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);`
the triangles is rendered.

But If I use:
`gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x/500, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);`
it's not rendered (I got a black screen, or whatever the color is defined in the `GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`.

That's lead to the question: **In GLSL numbers have to have decimal specification?**
Note that the only thing that changed in the code was the 500.0 number to 500.

**2nd** - **How can I retrieve the variable values that are inside the Fragment Shader Code to display them for example in a Toast?** Let me explain that question.

With these three code lines below:

`float colorTwo[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };`

`int mColorHandleTwo = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColorTwo");`

`GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandleTwo, 1, colorTwo, 0);`

I'm able to get this "colorTwo" array and used it inside the Fragment Shader Code.
In the other hand, If I have let's say a statment inside the Fragment Shader Code like:

`float whatThisNumber = gl_FragCoord.y`

How can I get this float and display it in a Toast?

The code below is actually the one I'm working on:

```
public class TheShape {

    ByteBuffer myByteBuffer;
    FloatBuffer positionBufferObject;    

    int mProgram;   

    public TheShape() {

        float vertexPositions[] = { 

                 0.75f,  0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                 0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f

        };

        myByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexPositions.length * 4);
        myByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        positionBufferObject = myByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        positionBufferObject.put(vertexPositions);
        positionBufferObject.position(0);

        String vertexShaderCode =
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                "}";

        String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColorTwo;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x/500.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);" +
         //ok   "gl_FragColor = mix(vColorTwo, vColor, (gl_FragCoord.y)/500.0);" +
         //ok   "gl_FragColor = vec4((gl_FragCoord.x)/500.0, (gl_FragCoord.y)/500.0, 0.0, 1.0);" + 
                "}";

        int myVertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(myVertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(myVertexShader);

        int myFragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(myFragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(myFragmentShader);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, myVertexShader);        
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, myFragmentShader); 

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);        

    }

    public void draw() {

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, positionBufferObject);



        float color[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };  
        int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);


        float colorTwo[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };  
        int mColorHandleTwo = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColorTwo");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandleTwo, 1, colorTwo, 0);



        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    }

}
```

I hope I was clear on my questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. In glsl language there is no automatic conversion from integer to float number, so the line of code `gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x/500, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);`  cause a compiler error.
2. You can not get the value of a shader variable from java code (or c++ code). The java code is executed from CPU, the shader is executed from GPU.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is about how java works and not related to OpenGL as such.

If you divide an integer by an integer, you get an integer. So my guess is that gl_FragCoord.x/500 results in a value such as 0.3 that then rounds to zero.

If you divide an integer by a float (or double), you get a float (or double). Hence when you divide by 500.0, you get the non-zero floating point result you expect. You could also achieve the same thing by using 500f. Either way, you let the compiler know you are working with a floating point value, which is clearly important here.

As for your second question, I don't believe you can although I'm happy to be corrected by someone else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, actually. GLSL is compiled by the OpenGL implementation (display driver usually), and `gl_FragCoord` is a floating-point 3-component vector. If you swizzle off a single component of this vector (x) you get a floating-point scalar. GLSL defines implicit conversion of integer types to floating-point when one operand in an expression is fp, so this should not be an issue. The only thing I can think of is the difference in precision between integer and fp - precision loss will occur during promotion to fp if the integer is larger than the mantissa supports.

Comment: Normally this would not be a major issue when converting the integer 500 to floating-point, but OpenGL ES 2.0 provides three levels of floating-point precision (two are required in a fragment shader, one is optional). A `lowp` floating-point variable, for instance, can only represent values in the range: +/- 2.0.